# Jenkins: withCredentials() can't access user scope credentials so is there any way I can use to access user credentials?

Tags: jenkins

I'm trying to configure a test job to access user credentials in jenkins with withCredentials() but it doesn't work. I use "Authorize Project Plugin" and configured the job with option "Run as User who Triggered Build"

```
node{
     withCredentials([usernamePassword(credentialsId: 'mytoken', usernameVariable: 'USERNAME', passwordVariable: 'PASSWORD')]) {
        usernameLocal = env.USERNAME
        passwordLocal = env.PASSWORD
     }
echo "echo vars: ${usernameLocal} - ${passwordLocal}"
}
```

Here are the first 3 lines of the output:

```
org.jenkinsci.plugins.credentialsbinding.impl.CredentialNotFoundException: Could not find credentials entry with ID 'mytoken'
at org.jenkinsci.plugins.credentialsbinding.MultiBinding.getCredentials(MultiBinding.java:153)
at org.jenkinsci.plugins.credentialsbinding.impl.UsernamePasswordMultiBinding.bind(UsernamePasswordMultiBinding.java:76)
```

You can see that it can't find credentials entry with ID 'mytoken' which is defined already in user scope.

I did a lot of search and found that it may be impossible to do it using withCredentials(). So, is there any way that I can access user credential scope?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Are you able to use something like this to access credentials in your job

```
pipeline {
    agent { label 'slave'}
    stages {
        stage('Example') {
            environment { 
                ARTIFACTORY_CREDENTIALS = credentials('artifactory') 
            }
            steps {
                echo "user: $ARTIFACTORY_CREDENTIALS_USR password: $ARTIFACTORY_CREDENTIALS_PSW"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This credentials is not marked global. 
Select Credentials - particular Credentilas - Update - Scope